# How to get the value of a range slider in real-time while dragging the slider?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following 2 buttons.

```html
<div class = "slider-container" style="">
    <div id = "x-slider" style="">
        X Axis<input id="XSlider" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="1.0" onChange="update()" /> 
    </div>
    <div id = "y-slider" style="">
        Y Axis<input id="YSlider" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="1.0" onChange="update()" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `update()` function.

```js
function update(){
    let x = document.getElementById("Xslider").value
    let y = document.getElementById("Yslider").value
    adjust(x, y)
}
```

The `update()` calls `adjust()` only when the mouse button has finished dragging. How can I have the `update()` function call `adjust()` in real-time while I'm dragging the slider and not just when I'm finished dragging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "slider-container" style="">
        <div id = "x-slider" style="">
           X Axis:  <span id="x"></span><input id="XSlider" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="1.0" oninput="update()"> 
        </div>
        <div id = "y-slider" style="">
           Y Axis : <span id="y"></span><input id="YSlider" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="1.0" oninput="update()"> 
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        function update(){
            let x = document.getElementById("XSlider").value;
            let y = document.getElementById("YSlider").value;

            document.getElementById("x").innerText = x;
            document.getElementById("y").innerText = y;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Please note that the onInput event is not supported in IE

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is change onchange to oninput.

Comment: This answer is correct but it would be be better if you also provided an example and an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, test to see console value

```js
var x = document.getElementById('XSlider')
var y = document.getElementById('YSlider')

function update( e ){
  console.log( e.target.value )
}

x.addEventListener('input', update );
y.addEventListener('input', update );
```

```html
<div class="slider-container" style="">
  <div id="x-slider" style="">
    X Axis<input id="XSlider" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="1.0" onChange="update">
  </div>
  <div id="y-slider" style="">
    Y Axis<input id="YSlider" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="1.0">
  </div>
</div>
```